# How do I sort an array?

Tags: rust

Why cannot I not sort an array as expected?

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = [1,3,2];
    let s = a.sort();
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`a` **is** sorted, but the method sorts the array in place. Read the [signature of `sort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort): `sort` takes `&mut self` and returns unit (*i.e.* nothing), so when you print `s`, you print `()`.

Working code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = [1, 3, 2];
    a.sort();
    
    assert_eq!(a, [1, 2, 3]);
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

## Writing a function that returns a sorted array

You can write a function that does what you want:

```
fn sort<A, T>(mut array: A) -> A
where
    A: AsMut<[T]>,
    T: Ord,
{
    let slice = array.as_mut();
    slice.sort();

    array
}

fn main() {
    let a = [1, 3, 2];

    assert_eq!(sort(a), [1, 2, 3]);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to sort without mutating the original variable?

Comment: @DamianDziaduch Just clone the array: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5c3bf2e7e151c177a14175e5f1a8f4cc

Comment: @DamianDziaduch Or use a sorted collection from the beginning

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios what do you mean by "sorted collection"?