# Why does a truncated string Rust print as an empty pair of parenthesis?

Tags: rust

I have

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("CHAR COUNT");
    let mut guess = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess).expect(
        "Failed to read line",
    );

    let string_length = guess.len() - 2;
    let correct_string_length = guess.truncate(string_length);

    println!("Your text: {}", guess);
    println!("Your texts wrong length is: {}", string_length);
    println!("Your texts correct length: {}", correct_string_length);
}
```

The last line gives me

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(): std::fmt::Display` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:15:47
   |
15 |     println!("Your texts correct length: {}", correct_string_length);
   |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `()` cannot be formatted with the default formatter; try using `:?` instead if you are using a format string
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `()`
   = note: required by `std::fmt::Display::fmt`
```

What am I doing wrong? If I use `{:?}` then I get `()` instead of a formatted string.

Comment: You should read the documentation a bit more closely :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sort an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888196/how-do-i-sort-an-array)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When in doubt, go to the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.truncate) - here's the function signature of `String::truncate`:

```
fn truncate(&mut self, new_len: usize)
```

Note two things:

- It takes `self` as `&mut`.
- It has no return value.

From that, the problem becomes pretty clear - `truncate` does not return a new truncated string, it truncates the existing string in place.

This might seem a little unintuitive at first, but Rust APIs tend not to allocate new objects in memory unless you specifically ask them to - if you're never going to use `guess` again, then it'd be ineffecient to create a whole new `String`. If you wanted to make a truncated *copy*, then you'd need to be explicit:

```
let truncated = guess.clone();
truncated.truncate(string_length);
```

Or if you just wanted to reference *part* of the existing string, you could do what Ryan's answer suggests.

Answer (score 5):

Just to compliment the other answers here..

Attempting to truncate a string in Rust that is not on a character boundary will cause a runtime panic.

So while this works now:

```
let correct_string_length = &guess[..string_length];
```

If you're trying to truncate a string with wider characters, your code will panic at runtime. This is especially true if you're truncating user input.. who knows what it could be. For example:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "Hello, 世界";

    println!("{}", &s[..8]); // <--- panic
}
```

You can use the [`str::is_char_boundary(usize)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.is_char_boundary) method to make sure you're not about to break up a wide character accidentally:

```
fn print_safely(s: &str, mut idx: usize) {
    loop {
        if s.is_char_boundary(idx) || idx >= s.len() - 1 {
            break;
        }
        idx += 1;
    }

    println!("{}", &s[..idx]);
}
```

User input could be anything so this is just something to consider.

Playground link: http://play.integer32.com/?gist=632ff6c81c56f9ba52e0837ff25939bc&version=stable

Answer (score 4):

`truncate` [operates in place](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.truncate), which is why it returns `()`. Looks like you’re just looking for a regular non-mutating substring:

```
let correct_string_length = &guess[..string_length];
```