# Why is rust raising error '`()` is not an iterator'?

Tags: rust

I tried to write a program that does the following thing: take all suffixes of a given string `s`, then sort these suffixes with dictionary order.

here is my code:

```rust
let mut sorted = (0..s.len())
        .map(|i| (i, &s[i..s.len()]))
        .collect::<Vec<(usize, &str)>>()
        .sort_by_key(|k| k.1);
for elem in sorted {
    println!("{} {}", elem.0, elem.1);
}
```

and rust compiler gives an error:

```
error[E0277]: `()` is not an iterator
 --> src/lt05.rs:7:17
  |
7 |     for elem in sorted {
  |                 ^^^^^^ `()` is not an iterator
  |
  = help: the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `()`
  = note: required for `()` to implement `IntoIterator`
```

Could anyone please explain what is wrong in this code?

Comment: Because `sort_by_key` is an in-place operation

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM But how should I fix the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888196/how-do-i-sort-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Vec::sort_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort_by_key) sorts a vector in place and returns [`()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.unit.html).  So in your code `sorted` ends up being assigned [`()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.unit.html), the [unit type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.unit.html) which you can't iterate over.

To fix this you can simply sort the vector after you've constructed it by moving the call to `sort_by_key` into a separate statement and then iterate over the sorted vector.  See example below.  Here is a [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=acbdef5821149c65f305bafde85ee930) which does this.

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = "thisisatest"; 
    
    let mut sorted = 
        (0..s.len())
        .map(|i| (i, &s[i..s.len()]))
        .collect::<Vec<(usize, &str)>>();
        
    sorted.sort_by_key(|k| k.1);
    for elem in sorted {
        println!("{} {}", elem.0, elem.1);
    }
}
```

Output

```
6 atest
8 est
1 hisisatest
4 isatest
2 isisatest
5 satest
3 sisatest
9 st
10 t
7 test
0 thisisatest
```

Comment: Or use [`Itertools::sorted_by_key()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.sorted_by_key).

Comment: Rather than answering a duplicate you should answer the dupe target so we can keep the knowledge in one place instead of spreading it across questions making it harder for everyone to find the best solution.

Comment: @cafce25 I think there are actually two confusing things here for people new to Rust: one about the `() is not an iterator` message and the other about how to sort the vector.  The answers I've seen regarding the sorting part didn't address the message in the title of the question so I think a complete answer explaining that part in the context of @creaple's original goal is worthwhile.